# TVN_SELCHANGING not received

Tags: c++, winapi, atl, wtl

I have a WTL81 app. CMainFrame has a child CPaneContainer, that has a child window CTreeViewCtrl. The problem is CTreeViewCtrl doesn't receive TVN_SELCHANGING message.

I have "spied" CTreeViewCtrl and his parent (CPaneContainer) and no notification code is received.

CMainFrame is implemented from public `CFrameWindowImpl<CMainFrame>`

CPaneContainer is implemented like this

```
class PaneContainerReflectNotif : public CPaneContainer 
{
    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(PaneContainerReflectNotif)
        CHAIN_MSG_MAP(CPaneContainer)
        REFLECT_NOTIFICATIONS()
    END_MSG_MAP()
};
```

Tree is implemented like this

```
class MyTreeView : 
    public CWindowImpl<CatalogTreeView, CTreeViewCtrl>,
    public CCustomDraw<CatalogTreeView>,
    public CTheme

   ...

BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX(MyTreeView )
    MSG_WM_CREATE(OnCreate)
    MSG_WM_DESTROY(OnDestroy)
    REFLECTED_NOTIFY_CODE_HANDLER_EX(NM_DBLCLK, OnDblClick)
    REFLECTED_NOTIFY_CODE_HANDLER_EX(TVN_ITEMEXPANDING, OnItemExpanding)
    REFLECTED_NOTIFY_CODE_HANDLER_EX(TVN_SELCHANGING, OnSelChanged)
```

OnDblClick - **works fine**
OnItemExpanding - **works fine**
OnSelChanged -  **doesn't work**

any ideas on what could be the problem ?

Comment: You don't see TVN_SELCHANGING at all?  Then nothing is being selected?

Comment: Items are selected normally, it's just I don't receive TVN_SELCHANGING notification.

Comment: Use the Spy++ tool to see what's going on.

Comment: I had spied both Tree and parent. It receives notifications (NM_CUSTOMDRAW, NM_KILLFOCUS, TVN_ITEMCHANGEING, etc) but not TVN_SELCHANGING ...

Comment: Try adding REFLECT_NOTIFICATIONS() to your main window message map.

Comment: Already there. Both in main window (CMainFrame) and Tree's parent. It's something tricky, but I don't figure out ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. My problem was that treeview was multi-selct and that kind of tree doesn't send TVN_SELCHANGING notifications

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned why do you need TVN_SELCHANGING. The event gets fired when the tree nodes are getting changed, and another tree node is being selected.

As an alternative, you might try TVN_SELCHANGED or HitTest( ). I am providing a MFC link .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w7ft34.aspx

Comment: TVN_SELCHANGING get fired when the selection is about to change from one item to another. This is what I need. TVN_SELCHANGED is also not fired, HitTest i don;t think it helps