# Confused by BEGIN_MSG_MAP and BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX

Tags: c++, winapi, atl, wtl

I am tracing a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613536/tvn-selchanging-not-received) and I suspect the root could be in the use of WTL macros. When sould I use *_EX and when normal macros. For BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX there is a note in atlcrack.h

```
// Note about message maps with cracked handlers:
// For ATL 3.0, a message map using cracked handlers MUST use BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX.
// For ATL 7.0 or higher, you can use BEGIN_MSG_MAP for CWindowImpl/CDialogImpl derived classes,
// but must use BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX for classes that don't derive from CWindowImpl/CDialogImpl.
```

but how about the rest or the macros ? can I use both COMMAND_ID_HANDLER and COMMAND_ID_HANDLER_EX in the same BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX because it supports more handlers. It also supports the BEGIN_MSG_MAP handlers.

Answer (score 0):

It will be safer if you add this to your main header file (probably `stdafx.h`)

```
#undef BEGIN_MSG_MAP
#define BEGIN_MSG_MAP BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX
```

So now code that is using `BEGIN_MSG_MAP` will be translated to `BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX` which is better in every aspect.